# (REOPENED) Request to reopen question on declining wedding invitation in Sri Lanka

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

This question [How to politely decline a colleague's wedding invitation given to you personally in office?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/90861/3192) was closed as primarily opinion based. However, it can be adequately answered with specific expert experience, in this case, "expert experience" with the Sri Lankan/Indian culture.

This is also an on-topic question about navigating the workplace, because the OP is specifically concerned about the social consequences *at the workplace* of declining a colleague's wedding invitation.

Please cast reopen votes if you agree, or post what can be done to improve this question.

(Disclaimer: I have posted an answer to the question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It had 3 reopen votes and I just cast the last vote.